# Parse Large Json File ( around 300 Mb ) to list of POJO

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization, jackson2

I have a large JSON file roughly around 300 MB, I am parsing it using Jackson object mapper:-

```
private void parseJson(Object obj) {

ObjectMapper map = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String,List<POJOClass>> result = new HashMap<>();
String str = map.writeValueAsString(obj);
map.registerModule(new JSR10module());
result = map.readValue(new ByteInputStream(str.getBytes(StandardCharSets.UTF_8)),
new TypeReference<Map<String,List<POJOClass>>>
() {});
}
```

Parameter to parseJson is an Object which contains JSON String.

This works fine for JSON files of around 150 MB, however, it starts to fail with `Heap Space error` when JSON files are around 250-300 MB. I am using `jackson 2.4.0`

Comment: How many entries are there in the data map? One string key and List of all POJOClass'es? Or multiple keys with multiple POJOClass lists?

Comment: Multiple keys with multiple POJOClass lists.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have enough memory in your `java` process to handle such huge file.

When launching your app use the `-xmx` option to increase the maximum memory used by your `java` process:

```
java -Xmx512m ...
```

or

```
java  -Xmx1G ...
```

Comment: This is running on t2.large EC2 instance with minHeap 4096m and maxHeap of 6144m

Comment: If you already tried this solution, you should use an other system to read your jsonfile like the `jackson streaming api`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried streaming over the JSON using, for instance: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-streaming-api so that you do not have to put everything into memory at once.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For huge big json file, you should use jackson stream api.
You can find the document [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonStreamingApi). It cost little memory than normal way. In general, your POJO must satisfy certain shapes, it should be able to be separated into many independent parts. Such as a list of object. Then with jackson stream api, you can achieve the object in the list one by one.